# How to know userAgentData?.brands? of google chrome of the android app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use this function to check if the user uses google chrome or not and it works fine if the user used google chrome in PC but when the user comes from chrome from android app it doesnot work
The function :

```
if (navigator.userAgentData?.brands?.some(b => b.brand === 'Google Chrome')) {
    
  window.location.href = "http://getfreewifikera.net";
  
 
      } else {
        alert("لتشغيل الانترنت من فضلك ادخل على رابط kwifi.net  عبر متصفح جوجل كروم");
  window.close();
 }
```

Comment: maybe `b.brand.includes('Google Chrome')`

Comment: so the code will be like that if (navigator.userAgentData?.brands?.some(b => b.brand.includes('Google Chrome'))    ?

Comment: yes, can try that in case the string has some text before or after the 'Google Chrome' - if that doesn't work just debug by console logging the value (or alert since mobile)

Comment: I don't know why but it worked from the windows only when we enter with google app on Anrdoid it just doesnot work , But i don't understand your B plan ?